# Make a vector path in xaml responsive

Tags: xaml, windows-8, windows-runtime, winrt-xaml

I have a canvas that is within a page in XAML that contains some paths from an .ai document. I would like this to be responsive and have resize according to the proportions of the grid that it is contained on. How?

Answer (score 0):

Okay I fixed it myself. Replaced the `canvas` with a `grid`, then enclosed that `grid` in a `viewbox`. All paths under the canvas now has horizontal and vertical alignment set to `left` and `top` respectively, and its Canvas.Left and Canvas.Top values are now replaced by a margin reflecting these values.